# How to concatenate number of rows to one in pandas DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas

How to concatenate ,for example ,every 3 rows to one with pandas as
the input is csv file ?

```
df = (pd.read_csv('sample.csv'))
```

from

```
10 ,11 ,12

13 ,14 ,15

16, 17 ,18

19 ,20, 21

22 ,23, 24

25 ,26, 27

...
```

to

```
10 ,11 ,12 ,13 ,14 ,15 ,16 ,17 ,18 

19 ,20 ,21 ,22 ,23 ,24 ,25 ,26 ,27

...
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Please provide your expected output
also [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: I added the expected output (can't do it before due to system limitation)

Answer (score 1):

You can reshape using numpy

```py
df = pd.DataFrame(df.to_numpy().reshape(3,-1))
```

Comment: Thank you Dishin H Goyani . It's the simplest way to do that.